# How to get post id by using post name and category name in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

How to get post id by using post name and category name in WordPress?

I have use this code but it not help me.

```
$post_slug = get_post_field( $post_name, get_post() ); 
$args = array(
'name'        => $post_slug,
'category_name' => $pcat_name,
'post_type'   => 'post',
'post_status' => 'publish',
'numberposts' => 1
);
$my_posts = get_posts($args);
if( $my_posts ) :
$rid=$my_posts[0]->ID;
endif;
```

the slug is not work.

I want to check with both post name and the category name it is must.

Answer (score 0):

You can use get_page_by_title() (https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page_by_title) to get posts or any other post type:

```
$posts = get_page_by_title($post_name, OBJECT, 'post');
foreach($posts as $post){
    if(in_category($pcat_name, $post->ID)){
        echo $post->ID;
    };
};
```

Comment: this is not i expected one. i need post id by using post name and also checks the category name.